# Words that have same spelling, different meaning, and different number of syllables?

Tags: syllables

Is there a term for words that have the same spelling, different meanings, and different number of syllables for their pronunciations?

The only example I can think of is *resume* and *résumé*. The only problem with this example is it technically isn’t the same spelling though since there are accents in *résumé*. But *resume* and *résumé* do have different meanings, and different number of syllables in their pronunciations. Are there any other words that someone can think of that have same spelling, different meanings AND number of syllables. And is there a term for these words?

Update: another “heteronym with varying syllables” I just thought of: blessed (used as a verb) would be pronounced “blest”, as in, "Uncle Joey blessed our Thanksgiving dinner", while blessed used adjectivally may be pronounced “blesid”, as in, "He loved his blessed freedom."

Comment: *Blessed* can be one or two syllables, though the meanings are pretty related and pronunciations are not consistently applied to the same meanings.

Comment: Update - you "just thought of" blessed? Coincidentally *after* I suggested it?

Comment: It was actually kind of weird, I was just editing my question and added blessed to it, and as soon as I submitted and refreshed, I saw your comment. You must have commented that at the exact same time I was editing. I legitimately thought of the word blessed a week before I even asked the question. Once I remembered, I started editing, then when I was done, I saw your comment. There is no way for me to prove to you that it was my original thought and was independent of your comment, but it occurred to me before I saw your comment. Think what you wish.

Comment: Different amounts of syllables? Are you weighing them?

Comment: @David No, I’m not weighing them. Light or heavy syllables, I don’t mind. If this doesn’t clarify, just tell me.

Comment: I'd weigh your words but count your syllables.

Comment: [forte](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forte#h1-anchor) and [forte](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forte#h3-anchor)

Comment: [Tier and tier](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tier) (*layer* and *one who ties*).

Answer (score 3):

The closest definition I could find is that of the [**heteronym**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronym_(linguistics)):

> A heteronym (also known as a *heterophone*) is a word that has a different pronunciation and meaning from another word but the same spelling. These are homographs that are not homophones.

Heteronyms don't necessarily have a different amount of syllables, but these are included. Other examples of heteronyms are *present*, *produce*, *lead*, and *desert*.

*Drawer* ('compartment in a cupboard'; 'someone who draws') would be a heteronym with a different amount of syllables.

Edit: these  are [apparently](http://www.fun-with-words.com/nym_heteronyms.html#Accent_Heteronyms) also referred to as '**accent heteronyms**'.

Answer (score 1):

(Seeing as answers are getting posted, which give *examples* of the phenomenon rather than a term for it:)

agape ['ægəpi] selfless Christian love

agape [ə'geɪp] with gaping mouth

coax [koʊks] to persuade by fondling or flattery

coax ['koʊæks] coaxial cable

manes ['meɪnz] long hair on the back of the necks of horses, lions etc.

manes ['meɪniz] (Roman myth) the spirits of the dead

moped [moʊpt] moved aimlessly and listlessly

moped ['moʊpɛd] lightweight motorcycle

Definitions adapted from, and pronunciations translated to IPA from, Chambers English Dictionary

Comment: Why don't you incorporate your earlier answer into this one, and then delete the old one - that way you can post these examples, and avoid the objection that the answer is not really an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Words which are written the same way are ***homographs***. I don't know of a specific term for homographs with different numbers of syllables.

Answer (score -1):

Wicked, past tense of wick has 1 syllable, the adjective has two. I'm guessing there are a few others that end in -ed, not sure if there would be any that don't.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).